# c-indent-line-or-region: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size

Tags: indentation, debugging, cc-mode

I'm trying to define a new major mode using `define-generic-mode` and want to try reusing `c-indent-line-or-region` for my `indent-line-function`. I've inserted

```
(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'c-indent-line-or-region)
```

in the initialisation part of `define-generic-mode` and it is correctly set. However, when I hit enter in a buffer using that mode I get an error:

```
c-indent-line-or-region: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
```

I've searched around and found suggestions to enable `debug-on-error`, which I have done, but the `*Backtrace*` buffer is always empty and accompanied by a message

```
Lisp nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: This means that you've exceeded Emacs's recursion limits. You can debug by just setting those variables to large numbers (e.g. `(setq max-lisp-eval-depth 10000)`) or by just adding `(message ...)` calls and watching where the recursion blows up.

Comment: Right, I thought that this was just another symptom of the same problem, but increasing `max-lisp-eval-depth` helped, thanks. I found that if you set `indent-line-function` to `c-indent-line-or-region` it is asking for trouble as it calls to `c-indent-command`, `indent-function`, `indent-according-to-mode`, and then back to `indent-line-function`.